# Roslyn Analyzer not working in VSIX instance

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, vsix

I was working on a Roslyn analyzer and all of a sudden, when I run the VSIX project, the analyzer seems to have no effect. I didn't change anything in the project, and the unit tests that test the analyzer still work, what could the issue be? The analyzer doesn't even show up in the VSIX instance (I checked by adding a .ruleset file and it used to show up there, but not anymore).

I noticed that Microsoft said that there are some bugs with the .NET template for the analyzer in this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix#prerequisites. Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Fixed it. To anyone that has the same issue, I removed some properties from the .csproj when I started, and for some reason it didn't cause issues until now, but adding those back from the template seems to have fixed the issue